# Can I buy an overseas property using the bonus from a Lifetime ISA?

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, savings, isa, house

I have a Lifetime ISA but am looking to move overseas in the next few months. I am yet to buy any property and thus my first property purchase will most likely be overseas, can I use my Lifetime ISA to fund this like I would over here in the UK?

Answer (score 6):

The government's own info on using Lifetime ISA funds to purchase your first home [here](https://lifetimeisa.campaign.gov.uk/#withdrawing_for_your_first_home), state that

```
The home you buy must:

- be in the UK
- have a price of £450,000 or less
- be the only home you will own
- be where you intend to live
- be purchased with a mortgage
```

That first point appears to rule out what you want to do.  So to use the Lifetime ISA funds for an overseas house purchase you'd presumably have to make a withdrawal subject to the Lifetime ISA's [usual penalties](https://lifetimeisa.campaign.gov.uk/#Withdrawal_Charge).